# Laravel 9 accessors and mutators - Simple example not working

Tags: laravel-9, accessor, mutators

So I am trying to get my mutators and accessors to work in Laravel 9, in my `Tag` model I have the following:

```
protected function name(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn ($value) => strtolower($value),
        set: fn ($value) => strtolower($value),
    );
}
```

When displaying the name in my blade view however, the name is not being displayed in lower cases (`{{ $tag->name }}`), also not when saving a new model to the database.

The following does work btw:

```
public function getNameAttribute($value)
{
    return strtolower($value);
}
```

Also when using `public` it does not work:

```
public function name(): Attribute
```

Just trying to understand what I am doing wrong here?

I am using Laravel version 9.44

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if the question's content is exactly your code. I had a similiar problem, get and set not working. But it worked in other model files.

I just found the solution once again, ya, once again.

If the attribute(column name) has two words, you have to make it together, first word should be lowercase.

**short_name**

```
protected function shortName(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn ($value) => strtolower($value),
        set: fn ($value) => strtolower($value),
    );
}
```

Comment: True, I knew about this, but mine has one word and is not working, and I cannot understand why

Answer (score -1):

Inject the class at top of page like below

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;